# Ada: is there a proper way for two types to "use" one another? Limited with + access = can't compile

Tags: types, reference, include, ada

I'm fairly new to Ada, and I'm having endless problems with types, references and inclusions.
Below I have two types that need to "use" each other: `Train` and `Platform`, I included the source code below.

Since a direct "withing" will not work (I understand two ada types can't "see" each other directly, or a circular inclusion error will occur), I opted to have a `common` package (also included below) that "`limited with`"s the other two, and also implements access types so that including `common` will enable a package to use pointers to `Train` and `Platform`.

However it seems that this is not a feasible solution either: while I can declare variables using the ref types defined in `common` I cannot actually access any method/entry on them. I highlighted the troublesome line in Railway-train.adb with a comment. When the compiler reaches that line it stops with error:

```
Invalid prefix in selected component "StopAtPlatform"
```

I know that Ada is very different from other languages, but as someone that comes from C# I really have problems understanding why it is so hard to have two types using each other and why thos "pointers" (access types) seem not to be working properly. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Please, if you can, refrain from any comment such as "why do you need to have two types use each other, that's a bad practise"... thanks :)

Source follows:

Railway-train.ads

```
with Railway.Common; use Railway.Common;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package Railway.Train is

   task type Train is
      entry Create(id : in Natural; capacity : in Positive; Route : Route_Array; me : Train_Ref);
   end Train;

end Railway.Train;
```

Railway-train.adb:

```
package body Railway.Train is

   task body Train is
      Myself : Train_Ref;
      Train_ID : Natural;
      Passenger_Load : Integer := 0;
      Passenger_Capacity : Positive;
      Train_Route : Route_Array;
   begin
      accept Create (id : in Natural; capacity : in Positive; Route : in Route_Array; me : Train_Ref) do
         Myself := me;
         Train_ID := id;
         Passenger_Capacity := capacity;
         Train_Route := Route;
      end Create;

      loop
         for i in Train_Route'Range loop
            Train_Route(i).StopAtPlatform(Myself); --ERROR OCCOURS HERE
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end Train;

end Railway.Train;
```

Railway-platform.ads:

```
with Railway.Common; use Railway.Common;

package Railway.Platform is

   protected type Platform is
      entry StopAtPlatform(Incoming_Train : in Train_Ref);
      procedure DepartFromPlatform;
   private
      Train_At_Platform : Train_Ref := null;
   end Platform;

end Railway.Platform;
```

railway-platform.adb:

```
package body Railway.Platform is

   protected body Platform is

      --Train occupies the platform. This stops the access to the platform by all other trains, until DepartFromPlatform is called
      entry StopAtPlatform(Incoming_Train : in Train_Ref) when Train_At_Platform = null is
      begin
         Train_At_Platform := Incoming_Train;
      end StopAtPlatform;

      --Train leaves the platform. This re-opens access to the platform by all other trains
      procedure DepartFromPlatform is
      begin
         Train_At_Platform := null;
      end DepartFromPlatform;

   end Platform;

end Railway.Platform;
```

And finally, Railway-common.ads:

```
limited with Railway.Platform;
limited with Railway.Train;

package Railway.Common is

   --Common stuff
   type Train_Ref is access all Train.Train;
   type Platform_Ref is access all Platform.Platform;

   type Route_Range is range 1..100;
   type Route_Array is array (Route_Range) of Platform_Ref;

end Railway.Common;
```

**EDIT:** as ajb's answer below points out, adding `with Railway.Platform;` on top of Railway-train.adb generates a compiler bug :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct answer is that you need

```
with Railway.Platform;
```

above `package body Railway.Train;`.  The reason is that `Railway.Common`'s specification defines `Route_Array` as an array of `Platform_Ref`, which is an access to a limited-view type (because `Railway.Common` says `limited with Railway.Train` and `Platform`).  `limited with` does not make detailed information about the types in `Railway.Platform` available, which is why `StopAtPlatform` isn't visible.  Adding a regular `with` to `Railway.Train`'s body makes that identifier visible.  It does not create a circular dependency, since it's on the *body* of `Railway.Train`.

However, when I tried this using GNAT, the result was a bug box.  I assume that's what you're using, since it gave me the exact same error message before I added the `with`.  So while I think this answer is correct, it may not help you until they can fix the problem.

I think the main reason why this is harder in Ada than C# is that Ada is an older language and was originally designed for the paradigm in which when you compile a file, the compiler must have all the information it needs.  A source file that referred to an identifier that it hadn't yet seen (because it was in a source file that hadn't yet been compiled) wouldn't work.  I think it's fair to say that the compiler technology available at the time just wasn't there yet.

**EDIT:** My earlier version made some misstatements about the structure of the program.

Comment: I can confirm, I get the "GNAT bug" dump as well :( Is there an alternative compiler I can use? Or am I just stuck until AdaCore fixes it??

Comment: @Master_T Unfortunately, the other compiler I tried this on also fails, for an entirely different reason.

Comment: This is weird tho, it doesn't seem such complicated code, I can't believe noone has ever written something similar and came across this bug... can we confirm it IS a compiler bug? Also, anyway to know what exactly is triggering it? I tried removing all references to Train from Platform and it still happens, so I don't think it's caused by the two packages using each other...

Comment: @Master_T Not sure what your question means... if the compiler output says "GNAT BUG DETECTED" then I think that confirms that there's a compiler bug.  Although your code doesn't seem complicated, sometimes using certain features in combination (`limited with` on two packages, tasks, protected types) causes unexpected problems, because not every possible combination of everything can be tested.

Comment: that's what I meant by "is this really a compiler bug", ie: maybe I'm doing something that is actually forbidden by the language but it hasn't been properly tested by the devs and shows up as a compiler bug while actually it's me doing something wrong... Unfortunately the compiler message doesn't give any info about what statement exactly is causing the problem...

Comment: @Master_T FYI, the other compiler I tried it on said your code was legal after adding the `with`.  (The compiler error occurred during a later phase of compilation.)  That's not a guarantee, since that other  compiler obviously has bugs of its own and could be missing an error.  But it makes it more likely that your code is legal.

Comment: @Master_T FYI, I've sent a report to AdaCore.

Comment: @Master_T I received a response that the program compiles correctly with the "development version of GNAT".  I was using a version from 2012; I haven't yet tried with the latest free version. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: FSF GCC 4.9.0 and GNAT GPL 2014 both show this problem, sorry.

Comment: @ajb: thanks for your efforts, I was about to report the bug myself. I was using the 2014 version of GNAT, is there a way to access the dev/beta version? Unfortunately I can't wait much time for this, I'll have to find a way to code it differently if I don't find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to declare both types in the same package.